# Openshift route redirects to cluster console

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, okd

I'm installing OKD v3.11 cluster with ansible.

Cluster configuration:

- 4 master-infra-etcd nodes
- 4 computing nodes
- 1 external load balancer

Load balancer configuration is described here:
https://github.com/redhat-cop/openshift-playbooks/blob/master/playbooks/installation/load_balancing.adoc#custom-certificate-ssl-termination-production

I'm using nginx as my external load balancer.

Inventory (truncated):

```
openshift_master_cluster_hostname: okd-internal.example.com
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname: okd.example.com
openshift_master_default_subdomain: okd.example.com
```

Here is my NGINX configuration:

```
user  nginx;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
load_module /usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_processes  "4";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept off;
}

stream {
    upstream okd_masters {
      server okdmaster01.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster02.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster03.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster04.lab.example.com:8443;
    }
    server {
        listen 8443;
        proxy_pass okd_masters;
    }
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout  120;
    keepalive_requests 10;

    server_tokens on;


    upstream okd_masters {
      server okdmaster01.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster02.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster03.lab.example.com:8443;
      server okdmaster04.lab.example.com:8443;
    }

    server {
      listen      443 ssl;
      server_name okd.example.com *.okd.example.com;

      ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/all.okd.example.com.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/all.okd.example.com.key;

      ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_session_timeout       5m;
      ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers               ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

      proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout 600;
      proxy_read_timeout 600;
      send_timeout 600;
      keepalive_timeout 600;
      keepalive_requests 10;

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;

      location / {
        proxy_pass https://okd_masters;
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I'm trying to access route (app.okd.example.com) I'm getting redirected to okd.example.com instead

Comment: Have you tried it without the load balancer (just to get set up)? That would help you identify whether the problem is with your openshift configuration or with your nginx configuration.

Comment: @lxop
Ok, thanks, I'll try